# Escaping strings inside a Twig extension

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm building a Twig extension that facilitates one function. This function generates quite a lot of HTML. Some (but not all) of the output of this function needs to be escaped. Therefore,  the function is declared as follows:

```
new \Twig_SimpleFunction(
   'my_function',
   array($this, 'myFunction'),
   array('is_safe' => array('html'))
)
```

Is there an easy way to use Twig's internal `escape` function to escape parts of this function's output?

It might help to know I'm inside a Symfony2 environment.

Comment: What about using `strip_tags` like `strip_tags($str, array('tag1', 'tag2'))` INSIDE your `myFunction` before passing it further?

Comment: Of course I can use PHP's escaping functions, although I was wondering whether it was possible to use Twig's.

Answer (score 0):

Twig's escaper is defined here: https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/blob/master/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php.

I guess it should be possible to create an instance of the class and call its method `twig_escape_filter()`.